# Passing a list from VF component to VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

How would you pass an LIST from component to page I have wired-up everything I think but I'm sure I'm missing something that I'm unable to see the results returning on the VF Page.

Here is the sample code:

VF Component:

```
<apex:component controller="CompController">    
    <apex:attribute type="ComponentData" name="compData" required="true" description="The data going in and out" assignTo="{!cData}"/>    
    <apex:outputPanel id="banManagerPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}">
            <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!updateData}"/>                
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

VF Component Controller:

```
   public class CompController {
    public ComponentData cData {get;set;}

    public string searchText {get;set;}

    public void updateData(){
        cData = new ComponentData();
        list<ComponentData> cd = new list<ComponentData>();
        cData.theInput = searchText + '-' + 'a1';
        cData.theOutput = searchText + '-' + 'b1';
        cd.add(cData); 
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="pageController" >
    <apex:form>  
        <c:comppage compData="{!theData}"></c:comppage>   
        <apex:outputText value="{!theData}"  />    
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

VF Page Controller:

```
public class pageController {
    public ComponentData theData {get;set;}

    public pageController() {
        //system.debug('///'+ theData);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public with sharing class ComponentData {
    public String theInput {get;set;}
    public String theOutput {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This is not a basic thing to miss. You are passing a class into controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, by assigning a value in the component's constructor, you break the association created by assignTo. Instead, initialize the data in the page controller, and it works:

```
public class pageController {
    public ComponentData theData {get;set;}

    public pageController() {
        theData = new ComponentData();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CompController {
    public ComponentData cData {get;set;}

    public string searchText {get;set;}

    public void updateData(){
        cData.theInput = searchText + '-' + 'a1';
        cData.theOutput = searchText + '-' + 'b1';
    }
}
```

---

I have tested and verified this in my developer org. Basically, the value that is passed in assignTo must already be initialized.

Alternatively, you could pass in the entire page controller, as outlined by @LanceShi.

```
<apex:component controller="CompController">    
    <apex:attribute type="pageController" name="controller" required="true" description="The data going in and out" assignTo="{!thePageController}"/>    
    <apex:outputPanel id="banManagerPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}">
            <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!updateData}"/>                
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

---

```
public class CompController {
   public pageController thePageController {get;set;}
   public string searchText {get;set;}

   public void updateData(){
        thePageController.theData.theInput = searchText + '-' + 'a1';
        thePageController.theData.theOutput = searchText + '-' + 'b1';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I'm wondering why you are not returning the collection from component controller?  if I try to return list from component controller i'm not getting anything back on the vf page but if I tried your code sample it does work, you can not return the collection?

Comment: @NickKahn The pageController is not aware of any sort of list, so there's no way you could send it a list. If you need a list, declare a list in your pageController, assign a new list value to it, then pass that list to your component. Your component, in turn, can use the add method to add items to the list.

Comment: i was still editing my question so yes i do understand that its not aware of the list but my scenario is other way round and i guess it applies the same but i will go ahead and ask you, my scenario is, pass from component controller to page controller. i will give it a shot and update you.

Comment: @NickKahn You need to give the component a reference to the controller, as in the second example, mentioned by both myself and LanceShi. You have to have a "reference" to the controller; once you have that, you can call any of the pageController public methods and access any public members, including giving the pageController a list of some sort. Maybe you should ask a new question, providing the details of what you're trying to do, rather than focusing so much on the code.

Comment: posted new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155785/building-a-search-component-that-returns-list-of-records

Answer (score 2):

The attribute you passed from your VF page to VF component is one way binding. The the value updated in your component won't update back into your VF page.

To pass value back from component into VF page, there is a blog talking about this issue: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

And here is the summarize version from Paul Battisson:

As a summary - you should pass in the controller of your page as an apex attribute of your component (just as James mentions). You will have your component look like

```
<apex:component controller="MyComponentController" >
    <apex:attribute name="pageController" type="PageControllerBase" assignTo="{!pageController}" required="true" description="The controller for the page." />
</apex:component>
```

Which on your page you will use as

```
<c:myComponent pageController="{!pageCont}" />
```

This will then assign the page controller returned in the "getPageCont" method on your page controller to the "pageController" parameter/property in your component. A method in your page's controller to return itself is needed for the "getPageCont" call.

```
public PageControllerBase getPageCont()
{
    return this;
}
```

Comment: One thing I am not sure when the attribute is a custom object type, is it passing by reference or a deep clone? Seems to be deep clone here.

Comment: Apex, like Java, passes by value. The "value" of an object is always a reference. You can indeed pass the controller back and forth between a page and the page's components.

Comment: @sfdcfox Then the scenario of Nick's situation is a bit interesting... He is passing a custom object, so it should be a reference. And it should got changed... Is it due to rerendering issue?

Comment: No, but I figured it out, I think... one sec.

Comment: I apologize. This answer is actually (mostly) on track. It's more accurate to say that the reference passed is one way; anything you update inside the reference will make it back to the controller. It's not necessary to pass the entire controller (as a matter of encapsulating the data), you can instead just initialize `theData` in the `pageController` constructor.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for pointing this out. I am always more interested in figuring out what it is than getting fake credits.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, here is my action function version:-

**Component:**

```
<apex:component controller="CompController">    
    <apex:attribute type="ComponentData" name="compData" required="true" description="The data going in and out" assignTo="{!cData}"/>    
    <apex:outputPanel id="banManagerPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}">
            <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!updateData}" oncomplete="rerenderZ('{!cdata.theInput}','{!cdata.theOutput}');"/>                
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="pageController" >
    <apex:form >  
        <c:comppage compData="{!theData}"></c:comppage>   
        <apex:outputPanel id="eval">
            {!theData}
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:actionfunction name="rerenderZ" rerender="eval">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!theData.theInput}" name="tdata" value="sds"/>
            <apex:param assignTo="{!theData.theOutput}" name="todata" value="Z"/>
        </apex:actionfunction>

    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**PageController**

```
public class pageController {
    public ComponentData theData {get;set;}

    public pageController() {
        theData = new ComponentData(); // This is the change
    }

}
```

> I am using action function to circulate values. OnComplete is pushing values back to page controller. Here, you can modify the type, design. # of arguments based
>   on your design.

Comment: That's relatively inefficient because it requires two round-trips with the server, but it's kind of cool to look at.

Comment: @sfdcfox its a kind of recursion. With this solution you can apply any creative approach to play with data.

Comment: It does not require to send entire controller. Considering view state.