# Building a search component that returns list of records

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm trying to build a search component where it will be used in multiple pages across the application.

the search component will consists of a inputText & commandButton when the user searches it will return a list back to the vf/controller to show the results (iterate the data and display).

The issue I'm having is that it's not returning the list back to the page controller.

VF Component:

```
<apex:component controller="CompController">    
    <apex:attribute type="ComponentData[]" name="compData" required="true" description="The data going in and out" assignTo="{!cDataList}"/>    
    <apex:outputPanel id="banManagerPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}">
            <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!updateData}"/> 
        </apex:inputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:component>
```

VF Component Controller:

```
public class CompController {

    public list<ComponentData> cDataList {get;set;}  
    public string searchText {get;set;}
    list<ComponentData> compList = new list<ComponentData>();
    public void updateData(){

        ComponentData c= new ComponentData();

        c.theInput = searchText + '-' + 'a1';
        c.theOutput = searchText + '-' + 'b1';
        compList.add(c); 

        c= new ComponentData();
        c.theInput = searchText + '-' + 'a2';
        c.theOutput = searchText + '-' + 'b2';
        compList.add(c); 
        cDataList = compList;
        system.debug('CompController compList:' + compList);
        system.debug('CompController cDataList :' + cDataList );
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="pageController" >
    <apex:form >  
        <c:CompPage compData="{!theDataList}"></c:CompPage>   
         {!theDataList.size}
        <apex:repeat value="{!theDataList}" var="v"> 
            {!v.theInput} <br/>
            {!v.theOutput} <br/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

VF Page Controller:

```
public class pageController {
    public ComponentData[] theDataList {get;set;}

    public pageController() {
        theDataList = new ComponentData[0];
        system.debug('pagectrl:' + theDataList );
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply pass in the `CompController` instance as an `attribute` instead.

Comment: This is much more useful than your prior question. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

When you made an assignment to cDataList, it broke the reference to the pageController (`theDataList` can't be updated).

```
    // This breaks the one-way association of assignTo
    cDataList = compList;
```

The easiest fix is to use the existing list instead:

```
    cDataList.clear();
    cDataList.addAll(compList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would structure it. I think it should work, but I haven't tested it.

**Component Markup**

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="controller" type="CompController"
        required="true" description="..." />

    <!-- other markup -->
    <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!controller.updateData}" />

</apex:component>
```

**Page Controller**

```
public with sharing class PageController
{
    public CompController searchController { get; private set; }
    public PageController()
    {
        searchController = new CompController();
    }
}
```

**Page Markup**

```
<c:CompPage controller="{!searchController}" />
```

Comment: `Error: Wrong type for attribute <c:comppage controller="{!searchController}">. Expected CompController, found String` on the vf page controller

Comment: Did you declare `searchController` as a `String` instead of a `CompController`? The code I posted would not throw that error...