# Save VF component's data using VF page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, controller

Guys please help me I stuck with one problem
I have one vf page which has 4 diffrent tabs, now for each tab I have visualforce component.
The visualforce component creates two diffrent objects.
I want to use only one controller for VF page and save the record of vf component using that controller.
How can I do this using one controller.

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
 <apex:form>
    <c:Component1/> <!-- uses Object 1, so need to save object 1 record -->
    <c:Component2 /> <!-- uses Object 2, so need to save object 2 record -->
    <c:Component3 /> <!-- uses Object 2, so need to save object 2 record -->
    <c:Component4 /> <!-- uses Object 2, so need to save object 2 record -->

    <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveRecord}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>    
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Can I also save the record using VF component's save button?

Comment: It is not doable in straight forward way if you are not passing any attribute value in component. Here it looks like that each component has it own controller.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am passing attribute values to my component

Comment: You should update your question with the attribute details also. However, I have given the approach in answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should be doable in this way:-

Assuming you pass the attribute in component. So, those values should be passed from the VF controller:

```
public class MyController 
{
    public Object_1__c object1 {get;set;}
    public Object_2__c object2 {get;set;}
    public Object_3__c object3 {get;set;}
    public Object_4__c object4 {get;set;}

    public MyController()
    {
        // Initialize these objects or fetch by query
    }

    public void SaveRecord()
    {
        update new List<Sobject>{object1,object2,object3,object4};
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
 <apex:form>
    <c:Component1 objectInstance="{!object1}"/> <!-- uses Object 1, so need to save object 1 record -->
    <c:Component2 objectInstance="{!object2}"/> <!-- uses Object 2, so need to save object 2 record -->
    <c:Component3 objectInstance="{!object3}"/> <!-- uses Object 2, so need to save object 2 record -->
    <c:Component4 objectInstance="{!object4}"/> <!-- uses Object 2, so need to save object 2 record -->

    <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveRecord}" value="Save" id="theButton"/>    
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Whatever changes you will make in these components will automatically reflect in page controller.

> If you are looking for more approaches, *here is the code golf*:
>   [Passing a list from VF component to VF page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155766/passing-a-list-from-vf-component-to-vf-page/155784#155784)